# matching and dispalying specific lines through python

Tags: python, python-2.5

I have 15 lines in a log file and i want to read the  4th and 10 th line for example through python and display them on output saying this string is found :

```
abc
def
aaa
aaa
aasd
dsfsfs
dssfsd
sdfsds
sfdsf
ssddfs
sdsf
f
dsf
s
d
```

please suggest through code how to achieve this in python .

just to elaborate more on this example the first (string or line is unique) and can be found easily in logfile the next String B comes within 40 lines of the first one but this one occurs at lots of places in the log file so i need to read this string withing the first 40 lines after reading string A and print the same that these strings were found.

Also I cant use `with` command of python as this gives me errors like 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6. **I am using Python 2.5**

Comment: what string do you want found?

Comment: Hi Eiyrioü von Kauyf, the first (string or line is unique) and can be found easily the next String B comes 40 lines after the first one but this one occurs at lots of places in the log file so i need to read this string withing the first 40 lines of string A and print the same that these strings were found

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
fp = open("file")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if i == 3:
        print line
    elif i == 9:
        print line
        break
fp.close()
```

Comment: hi ,need more help on this i have to search strings in a logfile where in which line this string will appear cannot be decided  like the first string can be in line number 4120 and second string comes in line 4154 the second string is like withing 40 lines of the first string and i need to read these strings and display them.Also i cant use with comand of python gives me errors like 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

```
#list of random characters
from random import randint
a = list(chr(randint(0,100)) for x in xrange(100))
#look for this
lookfor = 'b'
for element in xrange(100):
    if lookfor==a[element]:
        print a[element],'on',element
#b on 33
#b on 34
```

is one easy to read and simple way to do it. Can you give part of your log file as an example? There are other ways that may work better :).

---

after edits by author:

The easiest thing you can do then is:

```
looking_for = 'findthis' i = 1 for line in open('filename.txt','r'):
    if looking_for == line:
        print i, line
    i+=1
```

it's efficient and easy :)

Comment: hi ,can i do something like reading a file line and than matching the x line which is unique and than using for loop for 40 times to search for second string

Comment: what do you mean 'matching the x line' can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
def bar(start,end,search_term):
    with open("foo.txt") as fil:
        if search_term in fil.readlines()[start,end]:
            print search_term + " has found" 


>>>bar(4, 10, "dsfsfs")
"dsfsfs has found"
```